# Using subprocess and Popen with double quotes and cw="filename" format argument line

Tags: python

I've tried a number of ways - triple quoting and using format. But I seem to be unable to get the program running with the arguments formatted correctly. The program is a custom program which I managed to run with `os.system()` but since I require a more complex interaction, need to use `Popen()`.

Here is the format that I require:

```
cmd.exe -s cw="filename.xyz"
```

Where cmd is the windows 7 executable program. The format of the command line arguments required the double quotes and I suspect this is causing the issue. With the `os.system()` calls I used the following:

```
filename = r"""filename.xyz"""
```

I then built up the command:

```
command = 'cms.exe -cw=' + filename
os.system(command)
```

This seems to work, but I cannot replicate using subprocess and Popen:

```
args = '-cw=' + filename
p = Popen(['cmd.exe', '-s', args], universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line
```

I get the wrong formatting -it looks correct and if I copy and paste the printed out arguments into another window and run with the program, I get the program running.

I wonder if the filename is screwing things up.

```
filename = 'C:\\CWD\\CWD\\filename.xyz'
```

I've been suggested to try:

```
p = Popen([command, '-s', '-cw=%s' % (filename,)], universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1),
```

but this doesn't work either.

As an awful hack solution to this, I have created a .bat (Windows batch file) in the correct format and execute this file using Popen, however its an awful hack, but still cannot see why I cannot get the argument string to behave.

Comment: On a non-Windows platform, you'd invoke `subprocess.Popen(['yourcommand', '-s', 'cw=%s' % (filename,)])` -- no `shell=True`, and no quotes inside the inner command; on POSIX systems, specifying a precise argv and not _needing_ to have a shell try to interpret a string into an argument vector for you is the approach that provides the most control and the least opportunity for surprises.

Comment: (Again, on POSIX systems, quotes are all interpreted by the shell before the program being invoked is called, so when you call `something -s cw="filename.xyz"` at a shell, what's _actually_ passed to the program being called has no quotes at all, but is a literal C array, as in: `argc=3; argv={"something", "-s", "cw=filename.xyz", NUL};`. But I can't speak to Windows).

Comment: much the same for windows, but with more details

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks. I gave this a go, but didn't work either.

Comment: All your code is a bit inconsistent. In one place you're passing `-s`, and in two others you aren't. In one case it's just `cw=`, and in others it's `-cw=`. Etc. Please try to be precise and consistent in your examples -- if you were putting `-s -cw=filename` into your args variable as a single string, for instance, that would definitely not work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thats the nature of the program, it requires an empty '-s' and arguments of the form '-cw='. What else can I do to be more consistent?

Comment: @Navonod, you can put the `-s` in your other examples. You don't have a `-s` in your Popen example, or in your `os.system()` example; right now, you _only_ show it in your command-line usage example.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, because '-s' isn't the issue, its passing the double quoted string in.

Comment: @Navonod, that's only true if you understand your bug correctly. If you truly understood it correctly, you could fix it yourself. If you're putting `-s ` inside of your `args` string, you're **definitely** not using `Popen` correctly, and also simplifying your question in a way that hides what you're doing wrong (which would explain why you still don't have a correct answer yet).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How am I not using Popen correctly? You're being vague.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for amending your question -- doing so allowed me to rule out a running theory, in a way that continued back-and-forth in the comments was unhelpful with. (I didn't give an answer because I couldn't prove or disprove my theory, because the question wasn't showing the pertinent details). That said, `shell=True` would break the above code in the UNIX case -- `shell=False` is correct when passing an exact argv through -- though I can't speak to its effect on Windows.

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to actually resolve this, I'd start by replacing your `cms.exe` with an executable that prints out its argument list in an unambiguous form; then, run it both directly on the command line and through Popen, and compare the results. `Popen(["python", "-c", "import sys; print sys.argv[1:]", "-s", args], shell=False)` might be an easy place to start, comparing its results to `python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1:]" -s -cw="filename"` run at the command line. If the output matches, it's not the command line passing that's at fault and the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to admit defeat, but in the end, the only way I could do this was to create a DOS batch file with the parameters that are sent to the .exe file and then to keep creating a new batch file for every single set of input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss the = sign? maybe you wanted

```
args = '-cw=' + filename
```

(note cw=)

also do you really run cmd.exe? In windows cmd.exe is the name of the shell (well, terminal) so you can run into name clash once

Comment: Sadly just a typo in SO. No, I'm not calling cmd.exe

Comment: so... fix the question to be minimal and consistent